# type deduction with auto &

Tags: c++11, auto, type-deduction

Today I wrote some code dealing with binary tree. Later I noticed a bug in the code:

```
void find(TreeNode* root, int target) {
    stack<TreeNode*> myStack{{root}};
    while(!myStack.empty()){
        auto& top = myStack.top(); // here I used auto& by mistake
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I am confused with `auto& top = myStack.top();`. After the type deduction, what is the type for `top`? Is it `TreeNode &` or `TreeNode* &`?

How about if I used `auto* top = myStack.top()`?

Comment: You can use `typeid(top).name()` or `static_assert` to check the type.

Comment: `stack<int> myStack{{root}}` shouldn't compile. Do you really have a stack of `int`s? The question doesn't make sense if so. Assuming you meant `stack<TreeNode*>`, then `top` would be deduced as `TreeNode*&`. For `auto* top = myStack.top()`, `top` would be `TreeNode*`

Comment: Should be stack<TreeNode*>. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `auto top = myStack.top();`  will assign a local copy of `myStack.top()` to `top`.
   In this case the type of `top` will be `TreeNode*`.
2. `auto& top = myStack.top();` will assign a reference to `myStack.top()` to `top`.
   In this case the type of `top` will be `TreeNode*&`.
3. `auto* top = myStack.top()` will assign `myStack.top()` to `top`.
   In this case the type of `top` will be `TreeNode*`.

Comment: What is the purpose of "reference to pointer" in general? Never used that before. So in this case, auto and auto* are the same?

Comment: "reference to pointer" is used when you want to modify the pointer itself rather than what it is pointing to. Yes, in this case `auto` and `auto*` are the same because the type of `top` is a pointer.